# MySQL More Tables or more Columns?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm building a database for characters that would be analogous to DnD character sheets.  There are a lot of fields for any one particular character.  Like 100+.

Would it be more efficient to have one table with all the columns then save/load what I need, or separate out the columns into tables by category (like stats, equipment, skills, etc), then just join the one-to-one tables whenever I need certain info?

TDLR: Better to have 1 table with 100+ columns, or like 10 tables each with 10-20 columns?

Comment: It depends on whether those 100 columns are dependent on a single key or multiple keys.  Having 100 columns is not a problem per se because you might only be selecting a few columns at a time.

Comment: keep columns which should belong to 1 table in the same table ( 3nf normalization ) and do not split data just for the heck of it .. it should make sense and after that even if you're left with 100 columns in 1 table then so be it.

Comment: Metadata type structures is another possibility, Type/Value/Relationship table could also work.

Comment: What criteria are you using for "better"?  Generally speaking, though, 3NF is a good general guideline, in my rarely-humble opinion.

Comment: Sketch out the `SELECTs` for each case; that will help you (and us) decide.

Comment: Here is how I decide to split or not.  Integer value, keep it.  Free text (like comments), keep it.  Selectable value (I want to enforce a set of valid values), split it.  It makes it easier to query on these values later.  So with your question, stats I would keep in the user's table, equipment and skills I would split and get an association table, ...